# Find the probability of winning and losing!

Tags: probability

Imagine you're playing a random game with a very rich person (he has an infinite amount of money).

You have $m$ dollars at first and in each turn of this game, you win one dollar(you earn one dollar) or you lose one dollar(you pay one dollar). The probability of winning one dollar in each turn is $p$ and the probability of losing one dollar in each turn is $1-p$.

You will win the game when your money reaches to $N$ dollars and you will lose when you have no money.

What is the probability of your $(1)$ winning and $(2)$ losing?

I first found out that for example if someone wins with x failiures, then the answer for probability of winning will be equal to :

$\sum_{x=0}^{\infty} p^{N-m+x}(1-p)^{x}$ ${N-m+x}\choose {x}$

but it is not correct because of the occurrences for the steps than someone loses is not completely arbitrary and we can not multiply ${N-m+x}\choose {x}$ in each term of the above sum.

so I need help in solving this problem.

Comment: I think it is answered here: [Probability of Gambler's Ruin with Unequal Gain/Loss](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/207359/631742) but I don't have time to check the details

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch yes they are similar bot they are not exactly the same, and there is no solutions there!

Comment: Here also? http://www.columbia.edu/~ww2040/4701Sum07/4701-06-Notes-GRP.pdf

Comment: @Thomas yes,Thank you very much .

Comment: Or also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692161/gamblers-ruin-and-markov-chains?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just report the answer here [Gambler's Ruin and Markov Chains](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692161/gamblers-ruin-and-markov-chains?rq=1) by joriki generalized to this problem

The trick here is to consider $w_k$ as the probablity of winning starting with $k$ dollars. Than we have the recurrence relation:

$w_{k}=p w_{k+1}+(1-p) w_{k-1}$, $1 <k<N$

$w_{0}=0$

$w_{N}=1$

The characteristic polynomial of the recurrence is:

$x^2-x/p+(1-p)/p=0$

with roots $x_1=1$ and $x_2=1/p-1$, so that the generic solution is:

$w_k=A+B(1/p-1)^k$

Imposing the boundary conditions we get $B=-A$ and $A=\frac{1}{1-(1/p-1)^N}$

The solution is then:

> $w_k=\frac{1-(1/p-1)^k}{1-(1/p-1)^N}$